# WinApi - Get standard background color

Tags: winapi, colors, background, themes

I use `clrTextBk` for set the background color. But Windows system have many themes with different standard background colors. In example, Windows XP theme use color #316ac5, classic theme use color, like `COLOR_HOTLIGHT`, #0a246a, and nany others color, that used as `clrTextBk`. I can try use `GetSysColor` with param `COLOR_BACKGROUND` or `COLOR_DESKTOP`, but this colors is not a standard for `clrTextBk`. How get standard background color (`clrTextBk`) for current theme?

Comment: You would need to use the theme api

Comment: Thank you. I try use `OpenThemeData(hMainWnd, PWideChar('TEXTSTYLE'))`, but this give error: **SIGSEGV**.

Comment: How did that even compile? You can't have more than one actual character in a character constant. Plus, that's not even a wide character string! Anyway I'm not sure what your situation is; on what type of surface are you trying to draw? A tab page? The non-client area? Something else? If you could provide a screenshot that would help. Also are you talking about text background color or some other background color? Also the standard dialog background color is `COLOR_BTNFACE`, even with theming enabled, but you shouldn't need to worry about this depending on what you are doing...

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/gwk2u is not a `COLOR_BTNFACE`

Comment: It is not clear to me from your question **which color you're trying to retrieve**. The background color of the entire control in [the picture](http://imgur.com/a/gwk2u) is `COLOR_WINDOW` (in this case, white). The background color of the selected "Param #1" text is `COLOR_HIGHLIGHT` (in this case, some shade of blue).

Comment: The background color of the selected item - `clrTextBk`.

Comment: `clrTextBk` is not a standard name, so I don't know where you're getting that from. But the background color of a selected item is always going to be `COLOR_HIGHLIGHT`, unless the Aero theme is enabled (or on Windows 8 and later, where Aero is always enabled), where it won't be a solid color at all, but rather a blue glow effect.

Comment: You're right. This a `COLOR_HIGHLIGHT`. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, `clrTextBk` is a field of `NMLVCUSTOMDRAW`; that context is important. It'd have been more useful to put that screenshot on the original question, since you never mentioned anything about list views or selected items. Glad you found your answer, though!

Comment: @andlabs You're right too.That's my fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer (thank you **Cody Gray** and **andlabs**):

> `clrTextBk` is a field of `NMLVCUSTOMDRAW`

and I needed use `GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHT)`, order to get standard background color of the selected text.